# PHP regex wildcard url match with url

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match URLs with wildcards in them to actual URLs.

**For example:**

```
http://*.example.com/product/*/shop/
```

Needs to match

```
http://a.example.com/product/table/shop/
http://b.example.com/product/shoe
```

I have tried below regex so far and it is not working in all cases:

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_*]+\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+\.[a-zA-Z\.]{1,}[^\" ]+)/i

/([https?:\/\/])(\*.)?([^\" ]+)(\*.)?/i
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Are these urls contained in HTML tags? What have you tried so far to try and solve your problem?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried rather than asking for solutions directly.

Comment: Tried use `/s`, eg.: `/.../si` ?

Comment: You want to check if your wildcard url matches some other url?

Comment: Yes, if other url match the pattern then it allow process further.

Comment: Is `http://example.com/` or `http://example.com/product` valid?

Comment: Basically, I am trying a url that match pattern as http://*.example.com or http://example.com/* or http://example.com/product/*/shop/ or http://*.example.com/product/*/shop/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    $re = "/(https?:\\/\\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\.(example.com\\/product\\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\\/shop)\\/?/";
    $str = "http://a.example.com/product/table/shop/\nhttp://b.example.com/product/shoe/";
    $subst = "";

    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

[Live Demo here](http://regex101.com/r/rQ5lX8/1)